# node.js require all files in a folder?

Tags: node.js

How do I require all files in a folder in node.js?

need something like:

```
files.forEach(function (v,k){
  // require routes
  require('./routes/'+v);
}};
```

Comment: `var routes = require('auto-load')('routes');` with the new [`auto-load` module](https://github.com/Neamar/auto-load) [I helped create it].

Comment: Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules

Answer (score 594, accepted):

When require is given the path of a folder, it'll look for an index.js file in that folder; if there is one, it uses that, and if there isn't, it fails.

It would probably make most sense (if you have control over the folder) to create an index.js file and then assign all the "modules" and then simply require that.

*yourfile.js*

```
var routes = require("./routes");
```

*index.js*

```
exports.something = require("./routes/something.js");
exports.others = require("./routes/others.js");
```

If you don't know the filenames you should write some kind of loader.

Working example of a loader:

```
var normalizedPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "routes");

require("fs").readdirSync(normalizedPath).forEach(function(file) {
  require("./routes/" + file);
});

// Continue application logic here
```

Comment: To add some clarification: When `require` is given the path of a folder, it'll look for an `index.js` in that folder; if there is one, it uses that, and if there isn't, it fails. See https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native for a real-world example of this: There's an `index.js` in the root directory that requires `./lib/mongodb`, a directory; `./lib/mongodb/index.js'` makes everything else in that directory available.

Comment: `require` is a synchronous function so there is no benefits from callback. I would use fs.readdirSync instead.

Comment: Thanks, ran into this same problem today and thought "why isn't there a require('./routes/*')?".

Comment: @TrevorBurnham Thank you! I feel this should be added to the documentation.

Comment: @RichardClayton what would the return value be of `require('./routes/*')`?

Comment: @RobertMartin it's useful when you don't need a handle to anything exported; for instance, if I just wanted to pass an Express app instance to a set of files that would bind routes.

Comment: @RichardClayton I get that. I am pointing out that normally `require` will return the `exports` object. But in the case of requiring multiple files, it would not be obvious what should be the return value....

Comment: @TrevorBurnham To add, the main file (i.e. index.js) file of a directory can be changed via `package.json` in this directory. Like so: `{main: './lib/my-custom-main-file.js'}`

Comment: The return value of `require('./directory/*')` could be an object with as many properties as there are valid js files in the directory, the name of each property being the basename of the js file, and the value of each being the require of that single file. Its really pretty obvious to me.

Comment: What is '*'? A file named *.js inside the directory? I'm confused as to what your response means Cory Gross.

Comment: You'd want to guard against non-JS files with something like `if (path.extname(file) === '.js') require("./routes/" + file)(app);`

Comment: @TrevorBurnham I'm having to require all the files here like this. I dont know much about node.Is there anything I can do to iterate the objects without having to require every new file everytime https://github.com/abhayathapa/ember-blogger/blob/master/app/initialize.coffee

Comment: Note that the "working example of loader" above is incorrect - `readdirSync('./routes')` will read the routes directory in the current working directory, when you actually want to load the routes directory in the same folder as the source file.  It will appear to work if you run the file from the same folder as the file, but will fail if you try to run it from any other folder.  This should be `readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "routes"))`.

Comment: Jason, I believe that `path.resolve` will work as well.  I'll update OP with your fix for now and will update to resolve if that works too.

Answer (score 231):

I recommend using [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to accomplish that task.

```
var glob = require( 'glob' )
  , path = require( 'path' );

glob.sync( './routes/**/*.js' ).forEach( function( file ) {
  require( path.resolve( file ) );
});
```

Comment: Everybody should use this answer ;)

Comment: Best answer! Easier than all the other options, especially for recursive-child folders that have files you need to include.

Comment: Recommend globbing due to the overall control you have over the sets of filespec criteria you can specify.

Comment: `glob`? you mean `glob-savior-of-the-nodejs-race`. Best answer.

Comment: What variables does it save to? `var x = require('x')`  What is `var x` in this case?

Comment: glob.sync( __dirname + '/routes/**/*.js' )

Comment: Use map() for save links: const routes = glob.sync('./routes/**/*.js').map(file => require( path.resolve( file ) ));

Comment: Excellent answer, but no need to use `path.resolve( file );` ! Simply using `require(file);` since `file` is a filename that includes the file path

Comment: Warning to anyone trying to use this today with a newer Webpack version that it will cause issues due to lack of polyfill support. A number of the packages glob relies on are no longer provided by Webpack (path, assert, fs). Even with configuring webpack resolve fallbacks, I still could not get the solution here to run in a Webpack project.

Answer (score 77):

Base on @tbranyen's solution, I create an `index.js` file that load arbitrary javascripts under current folder as part of the `exports`.

```
// Load `*.js` under current directory as properties
//  i.e., `User.js` will become `exports['User']` or `exports.User`
require('fs').readdirSync(__dirname + '/').forEach(function(file) {
  if (file.match(/\.js$/) !== null && file !== 'index.js') {
    var name = file.replace('.js', '');
    exports[name] = require('./' + file);
  }
});
```

Then you can `require` this directory from any where else.

Comment: I know this is more than a year old, but you can actually require JSON files too, so perhaps something like `/\.js(on)?$/` would be better.  Also isn't `!== null` redundant?

Answer (score 71):

Another option is to use the package [require-dir](https://npmjs.org/package/require-dir) which let's you do the following. It supports recursion as well.

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
var dir = requireDir('./path/to/dir');
```

Comment: +1 for `require-dir` because it automatically excludes the calling file (index)  and defaults to the current directory. Perfect.

Comment: In npm there are a few more similar packages: require-all, require-directory, require-dir, and others. The most downloaded seems to be require-all, at least in July 2015.

Comment: require-dir is now the most downloaded (but notably it doesn't support file exclusion at time of writing)

Comment: Three years after Sean's comment above, `require-dir` added a `filter` option.

Answer (score 7):

I have a folder /fields full of files with a single class each, ex:

```
fields/Text.js -> Test class
fields/Checkbox.js -> Checkbox class
```

Drop this in fields/index.js to export each class:

```
var collectExports, fs, path,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

fs = require('fs');    
path = require('path');

collectExports = function(file) {
  var func, include, _results;

  if (path.extname(file) === '.js' && file !== 'index.js') {
    include = require('./' + file);
    _results = [];
    for (func in include) {
      if (!__hasProp.call(include, func)) continue;
      _results.push(exports[func] = include[func]);
    }
    return _results;
  }
};

fs.readdirSync('./fields/').forEach(collectExports);
```

This makes the modules act more like they would in Python:

```
var text = new Fields.Text()
var checkbox = new Fields.Checkbox()
```

Answer (score 6):

One more option is [require-dir-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir-all) combining features from most popular packages.

Most popular `require-dir` does not have options to filter the files/dirs and does not have `map` function (see below), but uses small trick to find module's current path.

Second by popularity `require-all` has regexp filtering and preprocessing, but lacks relative path, so you need to use `__dirname` (this has pros and contras) like:

```
var libs = require('require-all')(__dirname + '/lib');
```

Mentioned here `require-index` is quite minimalistic.

With `map` you may do some preprocessing, like create objects and pass config values (assuming modules below exports constructors):

```
// Store config for each module in config object properties 
// with property names corresponding to module names 
var config = {
  module1: { value: 'config1' },
  module2: { value: 'config2' }
};

// Require all files in modules subdirectory 
var modules = require('require-dir-all')(
  'modules', // Directory to require 
  { // Options 
    // function to be post-processed over exported object for each require'd module 
    map: function(reqModule) {
      // create new object with corresponding config passed to constructor 
      reqModule.exports = new reqModule.exports( config[reqModule.name] );
    }
  }
);

// Now `modules` object holds not exported constructors, 
// but objects constructed using values provided in `config`.
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is 5+ years old, and the given answers are good, but I wanted something a bit more powerful for express, so i created the `express-map2` package for npm. I was going to name it simply `express-map`, however the *people* at yahoo already have a package with that name, so i had to rename my package.

**1. basic usage:**

```
app.js (or whatever you call it)

var app = require('express'); // 1. include express

app.set('controllers',__dirname+'/controllers/');// 2. set path to your controllers.

require('express-map2')(app); // 3. patch map() into express

app.map({
    'GET /':'test',
    'GET /foo':'middleware.foo,test',
    'GET /bar':'middleware.bar,test'// seperate your handlers with a comma. 
});
```

controller usage:

```
//single function
module.exports = function(req,res){

};

//export an object with multiple functions.
module.exports = {

    foo: function(req,res){

    },

    bar: function(req,res){

    }

};
```

**2. advanced usage, with prefixes:**

```
app.map('/api/v1/books',{
    'GET /': 'books.list', // GET /api/v1/books
    'GET /:id': 'books.loadOne', // GET /api/v1/books/5
    'DELETE /:id': 'books.delete', // DELETE /api/v1/books/5
    'PUT /:id': 'books.update', // PUT /api/v1/books/5
    'POST /': 'books.create' // POST /api/v1/books
});
```

As you can see, this saves a ton of time and makes the routing of your application dead simple to write, maintain, and understand. it supports all of the http verbs that express supports, as well as the special `.all()` method.

- npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-map2
- github repo: https://github.com/r3wt/express-map

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28976201/1628984) `glob` solution. Do this if you want to import all modules from a directory into `index.js` and then import that `index.js` in another part of the application. Note that template literals aren't supported by the highlighting engine used by stackoverflow so the code might look strange here.

```
const glob = require("glob");

let allOfThem = {};
glob.sync(`${__dirname}/*.js`).forEach((file) => {
  /* see note about this in example below */
  allOfThem = { ...allOfThem, ...require(file) };
});
module.exports = allOfThem;
```

**Full Example**

Directory structure

```
globExample/example.js
globExample/foobars/index.js
globExample/foobars/unexpected.js
globExample/foobars/barit.js
globExample/foobars/fooit.js
```

globExample/example.js

```
const { foo, bar, keepit } = require('./foobars/index');
const longStyle = require('./foobars/index');

console.log(foo()); // foo ran
console.log(bar()); // bar ran
console.log(keepit()); // keepit ran unexpected

console.log(longStyle.foo()); // foo ran
console.log(longStyle.bar()); // bar ran
console.log(longStyle.keepit()); // keepit ran unexpected
```

globExample/foobars/index.js

```
const glob = require("glob");
/*
Note the following style also works with multiple exports per file (barit.js example)
but will overwrite if you have 2 exports with the same
name (unexpected.js and barit.js have a keepit function) in the files being imported. As a result, this method is best used when
your exporting one module per file and use the filename to easily identify what is in it.

Also Note: This ignores itself (index.js) by default to prevent infinite loop.
*/

let allOfThem = {};
glob.sync(`${__dirname}/*.js`).forEach((file) => {
  allOfThem = { ...allOfThem, ...require(file) };
});

module.exports = allOfThem;
```

globExample/foobars/unexpected.js

```
exports.keepit = () => 'keepit ran unexpected';
```

globExample/foobars/barit.js

```
exports.bar = () => 'bar run';

exports.keepit = () => 'keepit ran';
```

globExample/foobars/fooit.js

```
exports.foo = () => 'foo ran';
```

From inside project with `glob` [installed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob), run `node example.js`

```
$ node example.js
foo ran
bar run
keepit ran unexpected
foo ran
bar run
keepit ran unexpected
```

Answer (score 3):

One module that I have been using for this exact use case is [require-all](https://github.com/felixge/node-require-all).

It recursively requires all files in a given directory and its sub directories as long they don't match the `excludeDirs` property.

It also allows specifying a file filter and how to derive the keys of the returned hash from the filenames.

Answer (score 3):

Require all files from `routes` folder and apply as middleware. No external modules needed.

```
// require
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");

// apply as middleware
readdirSync("./routes").map((r) => app.use("/api", require("./routes/" + r)));
```

Comment: But why is `path` being requested here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [node modules copy-to module](https://github.com/node-modules/copy-to) to create a single file to require all the files in our NodeJS-based system.

The code for [our utility file](https://github.com/scottnath/pattern-library-utilities/blob/master/lib/utility.js) looks like this:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var copy = require('copy-to');
copy(require('./module1'))
.and(require('./module2'))
.and(require('./module3'))
.to(module.exports);
```

In all of the files, most functions are written as exports, like so:

```
exports.function1 = function () { // function contents };
exports.function2 = function () { // function contents };
exports.function3 = function () { // function contents };
```

So, then to use any function from a file, you just call:

```
var utility = require('./utility');

var response = utility.function2(); // or whatever the name of the function is
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using this function you can require a whole dir.**

```
const GetAllModules = ( dirname ) => {
    if ( dirname ) {
        let dirItems = require( "fs" ).readdirSync( dirname );
        return dirItems.reduce( ( acc, value, index ) => {
            if ( PATH.extname( value ) == ".js" && value.toLowerCase() != "index.js" ) {
                let moduleName = value.replace( /.js/g, '' );
                acc[ moduleName ] = require( `${dirname}/${moduleName}` );
            }
            return acc;
        }, {} );
    }
}

// calling this function.

let dirModules = GetAllModules(__dirname);
```

Comment: One suggestion for this answer, the current regex will match weird things like `"serverjslib.js"` and convert it to `"servelib"`, which would break things. Notice how the "r" in server was cut off. Thats because your regex is really matching "[any single character]js". Obviously that module name is terrible, but the same goes for things like `"express-json.js"`, `"load-json-file.js"` or `"parse-json.js"`, mangling the names into `"expresson"`, `"loadon-file"` and `"parseon"` respectively. This can be fixed by changing your regex to `/\.js$/`, matching only the literal dot and js at the end

Answer (score 1):

Can use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-file-directory

- Require selected files with name only or all files.
- No need of absoulute path.
- Easy to understand and use.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index.js file in your folder with this code :

```
const fs = require('fs')    
const files = fs.readdirSync('./routes')
for (const file of files) {
  require('./'+file)
}
```

And after that you can simply load all the folder with `require("./routes")`

Answer (score -2):

If you include all files of *.js in directory example ("app/lib/*.js"):

## In directory app/lib

example.js:

```
module.exports = function (example) { }
```

example-2.js:

```
module.exports = function (example2) { }
```

## In directory app create index.js

index.js:

```
module.exports = require('./app/lib');
```