# Cannot set a route in my Node.js Express.js application

Tags: node.js, express

I have my Node.js application and I am using the Express.js framework as well. The dir structure is the following:

```
myapp
  +-- node_modules
  +-- public
  +-- routes
         |-- index.js
         |-- mynewpage.js
  +-- views
         |-- index.ejs
         |-- mynewpage.ejs
  |-- app.js
  |-- package.json
```

The `app.js` file is like this:

```
 2  /**
 3   * Module dependencies.
 4   */
 5  
 6  var express = require('express')
 7    , routes = require('./routes')
 9    , http = require('http')
10    , path = require('path');
11  
12  var app = express();
13  
14  // all environments
15  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
16  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
17  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
18  app.use(express.favicon());
19  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
20  app.use(express.bodyParser());
21  app.use(express.methodOverride());
22  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
23  app.use(express.session());
24  app.use(app.router);
25  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
26  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
27  
28  // development only
29  if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
30    app.use(express.errorHandler());
31  }
32  
33  app.get('/', routes.index);
35  app.get('/mynewpage', routes.mynewpage); /* THIS LINE */
36  
37  http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
38    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
39  });
```

File `mynewpage.js` is as follows:

```
exports.mynewpage = function(req, res){
  res.render('mynewpage', { title: 'Hello' }, function(err, html) {});
};
```

When I try: `node app.js` with the line I marked uncommented, I get this error:

> /home/myuser/www/app-www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:252
>       throw new Error(msg);
>             ^ Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
>       at /home/myuser/www/app-www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:252:11
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Router.route (/home/myuser/www/app-www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:248:13)
>       at Router.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/myuser/www/app-www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:16)
>       at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/myuser/www/app-www/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:413:26)
>       at Object. (/home/myuser/www/app-www/app.js:35:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

If I uncomment that line, everything goes well.
What's the problem? Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You placed `exports.mynewpage` into `mynewpage.js` file, but not referencing it anywhere, and trying to use it from `routes` object.
While you've called `required` for `./routes` it will load only `index.js`, but not all files from that folder.

Just put the code for that callback into `routes.js` and it will work.

Comment: it is referenced in app.js: the first lines, you can see require('./routes') directive...

Comment: But it will not include all .js files, only index.js.
If you want to include all of them, then you need to reference each file individually.
Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364928/node-js-require-all-files-in-a-folder

Comment: Thank you a lot and sorry for doubting :)

Comment: 'You can't have faith without doubt' - Abraham

Answer (score 0):

```
var mynewpage = require('./routes/mynewpage');
```

will have to be required in order to call this the original way you created.