# Require all files in the list of folder without adding them individually in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I dont know much about node.Is there anything I can do to iterate the objects without having to require it everytime

```
folderOrder = ['routes', 'models','fixtures', 'views', 'controllers']

require 'routes/posts_route'
require 'routes/post_route'
require 'models/post'
```

Is there anyway all the new files I create in folders routes and models will be automatically required without having to require each one of them. My case for this example is https://github.com/abhayathapa/ember-blogger/blob/master/app/initialize.coffee

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have tried the answers in [node.js require all files in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364928/node-js-require-all-files-in-a-folder) but I get the same --- Cannot find module "fs"

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this (*if you were using node.js*):

```
folderOrder = ['routes', 'models','fixtures', 'views', 'controllers']

fs = require 'fs'
folderOrder.forEach (folder) ->
  dir = __dirname + '/' + folder + '/'
  files = fs.readdirSync dir
  files.forEach (file) ->
    require dir + file
```

**UPDATE**

After examining the example you linked, it seems that this has nothing to do with node. It's browser code, that uses brunch for managing build. However, in the `initialize.coffee`, there is already a commented code snippet which does exactly that, and it seems to work if you uncomment it, and comment out the 'manual' requires. I don't know why it is not used in the first place, though.

So, initialize.coffee should contain this:

```
# ===== Config =====
window.App = require 'config/app'
require 'config/router'
require 'config/store'

# Load all modules in order automagically. 
# Ember likes things to work this way so everything is in the App.* namespace.
folderOrder = [
  'routes', 'models','fixtures', 'views', 'controllers', 'helpers', 'templates'
]

folderOrder.forEach (folder) ->
  # Go through the prefixes in order and require them
  window.require.list().filter((module) ->
    new RegExp("^#{folder}/").test(module)
  ).forEach((module) -> require(module))
```

After editing the file, run `brunch w -s` from the root folder and it should be working.

Comment: I get Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs". Do I need to create index.js inside my app folder.This is where initialize.coffee resides.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it still doesnt work for me.Can you just pull my code and make it run. If I individually require all files, it works perfectly. But, if I comment out the code as you said or try what you have written above, it doesnt work. I have no clue what I'm supposed to do here.Am I missing sth on package.json ? Do I need express ??

Comment: So, how do you run it? and what error do you get if you uncomment lines 7-16 of [initialize.coffee](https://github.com/abhayathapa/ember-blogger/blob/master/app/initialize.coffee) and comment everything below that?

Comment: Could you please pull the repo and make it work, it would mean massive favour. If i use ur code,I get cant find module 'fs'. I get this error. ```Uncaught TypeError: Object function (name) {
    var path = expand(name, '.');

    if (has(cache, path)) return cache[path];
    if (has(modules, path)) return initModule(path, modules[path]);

    var dirIndex = expand(path, './index');
    if (has(cache, dirIndex)) return cache[dirIndex];
    if (has(modules, dirIndex)) return initModule(dirIndex, modules[dirIndex]);```

    throw new Error('Cannot find module "' + name + '"');
  } has no method

Comment: **DO NOT** add the code I posted at first. Make a fresh git clone, uncomment the lines that I mentioned in my previous comment, run `brunch w -s` and it's working.

Comment: Yes, its working because there is already require for all the folders, routers, models,etc that is line 24 to 46. If I remove line 24-46 and uncomment 6-16, it doesnt work. I added line 24-46 just because my line 6-16 didnt work. Did you get it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep I'm using something like :

```
fs = require 'fs'
requiredFiles = {}

for file in fs.readdirSync __dirname when file isnt 'index.coffee'
    requiredFiles[file.replace /\.coffee$/, ""] = require "./#{file}"

# requiredFiles is populated with all files in the current path, except index.coffee
```

Comment: I get Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs". Do I need to create index.js inside my app folder.This is where initialize.coffee resides? Is there sth Im missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something similar to @mutil, but would instead put that logic in each given folder.

Given an array of paths, an index.coffee in each folder:

```
fs = require 'fs'

module.exports = (path)->
  fs.readdir "./#{path}", (err, files) ->
    if err?
      return err
    else
      return (require "./#{file}" for file in files when file isnt 'index.coffee' and file isnt '.DS_Store')
```

with

```
for folder in folderOrder
  require("./#{folder}")(folder) for folder in folderOrder
```

in initialize.coffee, but you may run into some async issues depending.

Comment: I still get same error ' Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs" '. And its quite cumbersome to add index.coffee for all these folders.Dont u think ? Is it something I'm missing big time :(

Comment: That error is odd, because fs is a core node module; not sure what would allow you to run a node app that wouldn't be able to import that module. I also think this method is nice because it lets you have a mass import statement but still let you granularly control how each folder is imported (skip/process files, etc).