# What is index.js used for in node.js projects?

Tags: node.js, libraries

Other than a nice way to require all files in a directory ([node.js require all files in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364928/node-js-require-all-files-in-a-folder)), what is `index.js` used for mainly?

Comment: And examples on how to make native nodejs addons with Napi seem to use `binding.js` and have no `index.js` file - but it doesn't seem to be discussed anywhere. I also commonly see `main.js` or `Main.js`. I suspect but can't confirm so far that of these only `index.js` has a special meaning in Node.

Answer (score 67):

When you pass a folder to Node's require(), it will check for a package.json for an endpoint. If that isn't defined, it checks for index.js, and finally index.node (a c++ extension format). So the index.js is most likely the entry point for requiring a module.

See the official Docs here: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules.

Also, you ask how to require all the files in a directory. Usually, you require a directory with an index.js that exposes some encapsulated interface to those files; the way to do this will be different for ever module. But suppose you wanted to include a folder's contents when you include the folder (note, this is not a best practice and comes up less often than you would think). Then, you could use an index.js that loads all the files in the directory synchronously (setting exports asynchronously is usually asking for terrible bugs) and attaches them to module.exports like so:

```
var path = require('path'),
    dir = require('fs').readdirSync(__dirname + path.sep);

dir.forEach(function(filename){

    if(path.extname(filename) === '.js' && filename !== 'index.js'){
        var exportAsName = path.basename(filename);
        module.exports[exportAsName] = require( path.join( __dirname, filename) );
    }

});
```

I hardly ever see people wanting to use that pattern though - most of the time you want your index.js to go something like

```
var part1 = require('./something-in-the-directory'),
    part2 = require('./something-else');
....
module.exports = myCoolInterfaceThatUsesPart1AndPart2UnderTheHood;
```

Answer (score 17):

Typically in other languages the web server looks for certain files to load first when visiting a directory like / in priority, traditionally this is either: index or default. In php it would be index.php or just plain HTML it would be index.html

In Node.js, Node itself is the web server so you *don't need* to name anything index.js but it's *easier for people to understand* which file to run **first**.

index.js typically handles your app startup, routing and other functions of your application and does require other modules to add functionality. If you're running a website or web app it would also handle become a basic HTTP web server replacing the role of something more traditional like Apache.

Comment: I'm talking more to do with code/project management and the functionality of `require()` as opposed to serving pages; one example being the link I provided.

Comment: This is valid for a generic Node project. In case the project is a library, then [`index.js` should provide the module API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21760806/3088045).

Answer (score 10):

Here is a good article explaining how Node.js looks for required module https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8, with folder and `index.js` file

> Modules don’t have to be files. We can also create a find-me folder
>   under node_modules and place an index.js file in there. The same
>   require('find-me') line will use that folder’s index.js file:

```
~/learn-node $ mkdir -p node_modules/find-me
~/learn-node $ echo "console.log('Found again.');" > node_modules/find-me/index.js
~/learn-node $ node
> require('find-me');
Found again.
{}
>
```

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party but the answer is simply to allow a developer to specify the public api of the folder!

When you have a bunch of JavaScript files in a folder, only a small subset of the functions and values exported from these files should exportable outside of the folder. These carefully selected functions are the public apis of the folder and should be explicitly exported (or re-exported) from the index.js file. Thus, it serves an architectural purpose.