# Require a directory in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I've seen [several ES6 code examples](https://github.com/emmenko/redux-react-router-async-example/blob/ccfe333305425035ba6fc5335b01683f444a35e0/lib/utils/configure-store.js#L6) where a directory is being required, like this:

```
import * as things from '../some_directory'
```

Where `some_directory` is a directory, not a regular file. It appears that in this case `some_directory/index.js` ends up getting required.

Is this the case? Where is this documented?

Comment: Seems like this is related to NodeJS's [index.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063587/what-is-index-js-typically-used-for-in-node-js-projects) support. I don't think this would work in a browser

Comment: This behavior is defined by whatever loader happens to be in use.

Comment: Actually some documentation is presented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), part **Folders as Modules**

Comment: related: [import modules from files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29722270/1048572)