# Why does npm init set the main key in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I recently ran `npm init -y` and noticed this line in `package.json`:

```
  "main": "index.js",
```

Why does `npm init -y` set this key explicitly set to the default value? Wouldn’t it be cleaner to exclude it and just use the convention of loading `index.js`?

I want to remove the line from my `package.json` but I am assuming that `npm init -y` put it there for a good reason. I have yet to come across such a reason. Please let me know if it included `"main"` for a reason or if it can be safely deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is index.js typically used for in node.js projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063587/what-is-index-js-typically-used-for-in-node-js-projects)

Comment: sorry its a typo, it will not cause an error. if you don't want to get into troble, you can use `npm init` which will let you decide your main file. if not after generating `package.json` you have to provide right entry point.