# Node.js, require all modules in folder and use loaded module directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, require

In *MyModule* folder, I have this two JS files.

***SayHello.js***

```
module.exports.SayHello = function() {
    return('Hello !');
}
```

***SayByeBye.js***

```
module.exports.SayByeBye = function() {
    return('Bye Bye!');
}
```

In Node.js, I want to require all files in *MyModule* folder and call function `SayHello` & `SayByeBye` directly something like:

```
require(./MyModule) 
console.log(SayHello());
console.log(SayByeBye());
```

**EDIT:**

With answer of @[Yanick Rochon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320700/yanick-rochon),I do this :

**> ./app/my-module/index.js**

```
global.SayHello = require('./my-module/SayHello').SayHello;
global.SayByeBye = require('./my-module/SayByeBye').SayByeBye;
```

**> ./app/my-module/say-hello.js**

```
module.exports.SayHello = function() {
    return('Hello !');
};
```

**> ./app/my-module/say-byebye.js**

```
module.exports.SayByeBye = function() {
    return('Bye Bye !');
};
```

**> ./app/main.js**

```
require('./my-module');
console.log(SayHello());
console.log(SayByeBye());
```

There's a section about [global objects](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects) in the node documentation.

However, globals should be used with care. By adding modules to the global space I reduce testability and encapsulation. But in this case, I think using this method is acceptable.

Comment: You shouldn't put the module before exports, instead simply do `exports.SayHello = function.....` see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657341/node-js-require-all-modules-in-folder-and-use-loaded-module-directly

Comment: Daniel, the link is this post ?

Comment: @LeMoussel oops http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js

Comment: Not related, but why are your file names reversed? Its bothering me more than I would care to admit.

Comment: There must be a mistake. I corrected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js require all files in a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364928/node-js-require-all-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### First thing first...

I believe you are mistaking Node.js with PHP or .Net, in the sense that you don't "import" into the current module what is exported in other modules. Not unless you manually do it anyway. For example, when you call

```
require('./my-module');
```

*(Note that I renamed your `MyModule` into Node.js naming convention.)*

You don't load things into the current context; you just load the script and don't assign it to anything. To access what `my-module` exposes, you need to assign it, or use it directly. For example :

```
require('./my-module').someFunction();
```

or

```
var myModule = require('./my-module');

myModule.someFunction();
```

Modules are not namespaces, but JavaScript objects that exposes public properties outside of their own contexts (i.e. using `module.exports = ...`)

### Answer

You have two most popular ways to accomplish this :

#### Solution 1

Create an `index.json` file inside your folder where you want to load all of your scripts. The returned JSON object should be all the modules to load automatically :

**> ./app/index.json**

```
[
  "say-hello.js",
  "say-goodbye.js"
]
```

You should also consider having all your files API compatible :

**> ./app/say-hello.js**

```
module.exports = function sayHello() {
  return 'Hello !';
};
```

**> ./app/say-goodbye.js**

```
module.exports.sayGoodbye = function () {
  return 'Goodbye !';
};
```

Then load and execute everything like this :

```
var path = require('path');
var basePath = './app/';

var files = require(basePath);

var mods = files.forEach(function (loaded, file) {
  var mod = require(path.join(basePath, file));

  // mod is a function with a name, so use it!
  if (mod instanceof Function) {
    loaded[mod.name] = mod;
  } else {
    Object.keys(mod).forEach(function (property) {
      loaded[property] = mod.property;
    });
  }
}, {});

mods.sayHello();
mods.sayGoodbye();
```

#### Solution 2

Read all `.js` files inside your folder and import them. I highly recommend you use [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) for this.

```
var glob = require("glob")
var path = require('path');
var basePath = './app/';

var mods = glob.sync(path.join(basePath, '*.js')).reduce(function (loaded, file) {
  var mod = require(file);

  // mod is a function with a name, so use it!
  if (mod instanceof Function) {
    loaded[mod.name] = mod;
  } else {
    Object.keys(mod).forEach(function (property) {
      loaded[property] = mod.property;
    });
  }

  return loaded;
}, {});

mods.sayHello();
mods.sayGoodbye();
```

---

## Note on the difference between `module.exports` and `exports`

Typically `module.exports === exports`, but it is recommended to use `module.exports` for the following reason

```
exports = function Foo() { }         // will not do anything
module.exports = function Foo() { }  // but this will do what you expect

// however these two lines produce the same result
exports.foo = 'Bar';
module.exports.foo = 'Bar';
```

For this reason, `module.exports` is recommended in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect, but something like this should help you accomplish this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
var ownFilename = __filename.substr(__filename.lastIndexOf(path.delimiter) + 1);

var modules = {};
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var filename = files[i];
        if (filename.substr(-3) === '.js' && filename !== ownFilename) {
                modules[filename.slice(0, -3)] = require('./' + filename);
        }
}

console.log(modules.SayByeBye());
console.log(modules.SayHello());
```