# Node.js Express export routes for organization?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Utilizing express.Router() for API calls to/from our application:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var router  = express.Router();
```

`router.use` console.logs before every API call:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) { // run for any & all requests
    console.log("Connection to the API.."); // set up logging for every API call
    next(); // ..to the next routes from here..
});
```

How do we export our routes to `folder/routes.js` and access them from our main **app.js**, where they are currently located:

```
router.route('/This') // on routes for /This
    // post a new This (accessed by POST @ http://localhost:8888/api/v1/This)
    .post(function(req, res) {
        // do stuff
    });

router.route('/That') // on routes for /That
    // post a new That (accessed by POST @ http://localhost:8888/api/v1/That)
    .post(function(req, res) {
        // do stuff
    });
```

...when we prefix every route with:

```
app.use('/api/v1', router); // all of the API routes are prefixed with '/api' version '/v1'
```

Answer (score 12):

In your new routes module (eg in `api/myroutes.js`), export the module.

```
var express     = require('express');
var router      = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Connection to the API..');
  next();
});

router.route('/example')
  .get(function(req, res) { });
  .post(function(req, res) { });


module.exports = router;
```

Then you can require the module in your main server/app file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();


var myRoutes = require('./api/myRoutes');

app.use('/api', myRoutes); //register the routes
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `module.exports = router;` instead of `module.exports = myRouter;`?

Comment: @76484 yes, i've correct it and cleaned some things up. Sorry - I posted this a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

In your app.js file you can have the following:

```
//api
app.use('/', require('./api'));
```

In the folder `api` you can have 'index.js` file, where you can write something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//API version 1
router.use('/api/v1', require('./v1'));

module.exports = router;
```

In the folder `v1` file `index.js` something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/route1', require('./route1'));
router.use('/route2', require('./route2'));

module.exports = router;
```

File `route1.js` can have the following structure:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
    .get(getRouteHandler)
    .post(postRouteHandler);

function getRouteHandler(req, res) {
    //handle GET route here
}

function postRouteHandler(req, res) {
    //handle POST route here
}

module.exports = router;
```

`route2.js` file can have the same structure.

I think this is very comfortable for developing the node project.

Comment: So far this is the closest example I've found to the one here http://start.jcolemorrison.com/quick-tip-organizing-routes-in-large-express-4-x-apps/ however in this case there seems to be an immediate hierarchy for the base router in index.js and the routers underneath. Is there any performance or configurability differences between these approaches?

Comment: I was also wondering how index.js as picked up by simply writing `require('./api')` but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5365577/83658) to another question on SO answered my question.