# variable not defined in express js but the main app is imported

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new with express/nodejs and all of this.
I try to include `app.js` and `myCustomCsrf.js` inside 'index.js' and is seems that is not working.

index.js

```
const app = require("./app.js");

const PORT = 5000
app.listen(PORT)


require("./myCustomCsrf.js")


app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/build/index.html'), function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
})
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const mysql = require('mysql');

const crypto = require('crypto');

const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const csrf = require('csurf')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const session = require('express-session');
const { generateKey } = require('crypto');

// setup route middlewares
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
const parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// create express app
const app = express()

const corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// setup session
app.use(session(
    {
        key: "guestSession",
        secret: "yourSecretHere",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        }
    }
))

// parse cookies
// we need this because "cookie" is true in csrfProtection
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")))
app.use(express.json())



module.exports = app
```

and this is myCustomCsrf.js

```
const app = require("../app");

// set his csrf value in useState in frontend (react)
app.get("/api/checkguest", csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
    res.send({value: req.csrfToken() })
});
```

I know that I did not "include" the myCustomCsrf.js right. How can I do that?

Error:

`ReferenceError: csrfProtection is not defined`

I've tried many things, I really don't know what should I try again..

**EDIT:** I've solved this by using **router** https://stackoverflow.com/a/32284319/16661760

Comment: You’re not exporting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export `csrfProtection` From app.js and use it in myCustomCsrf.js

in app.js:

```
module.exports = {app, csrfProtection}
```

in myCustomCsrf.js:

```
const  {app, csrfProtection} = require("../app");

// set his csrf value in useState in frontend (react)
app.get("/api/checkguest", csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
    res.send({value: req.csrfToken() })
});
```

also make changes in index.js file while importing app

in index.js:

```
const  {app} = require("../app");

const PORT = 5000
app.listen(PORT)


require("./myCustomCsrf.js")


app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/build/index.html'), function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: now its saying this error: `app.listen is not a function`

Comment: You are supposed to make changes index.js also. I have Edited the post please check it.

Comment: Yes i don't get that error anymore, but i get this on same the next line: ``req.csrfToken is not a function``. is a better way to include all the files inside index.js?

Comment: csurf npm Package is deprecated try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dr.pogodin/csurf

Comment: Also You have to use csrfProtection Middleware in every rout for it to work