# Auto-generate index.js exports based on list of files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, commonjs

I'm using TypeScript and have all of my JS files compiled to `./dist/`. I want to enumerate these JS files and write a line to `./index.js` for each file:

```
module.exports.{filename} = require("./dist/{filename}").{filename};
```

Example:

```
module.exports.MyClass1 = require("./dist/MyClass1").MyClass1;
module.exports.MyClass2 = require("./dist/MyClass2").MyClass2;
module.exports.MyClass3 = require("./dist/MyClass3").MyClass3;
// ... etc. ...
```

This would auto-export all of my classes so that I don't have to do it by hand. I need to implement this as a gulp task, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.

Comment: Why not just require the classes you need? What problem is that `index.js` supposed to solve? And if you need to just use all files in a directory, why do it as a gulp task? You could just do this programmatically. Who told you to implement it as a gulp task?

Comment: I'd like to see an example of your suggestion; it may work fine for me. Currently I have no `index.js` at all because I was planning on importing the classes I need directly from the `./dist` dir. But it seems to be less user-friendly this way. If I add the exports to `index.js`, Then I can just `const MyModule = require("MyModule"); var x = new MyModule.Class1(...)`.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Node.JS so please correct me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: From your profile I was guessing that you maybe are trying to do C# stuff in node.js, which will probably be not the best way. It would be helpful to see what you are trying to do with the `index.js`, to better understand. Could you provide the part where you require the index.js and then do something with it?

Comment: Then maybe this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5365577/387573

Comment: @migg, you may be right about my background and what I'm trying to do. Really I'm simply trying to expose all my exported classes in the most "node-friendly" way. Your link is pretty much exactly what I need to do, I just wanted to automate it via gulp during the build process. For more context, here is the project I'm talking about: https://github.com/QuantumConcepts/js-base -- all of the TS files are compiled to `./dist/`, and I want to fill `./index.js` with those exported modules.

Comment: @migg, if you create an answer regarding your "then maybe this is what you need" comment/link above, I'll accept it. I ended up using similar code to that other question/answer.

Comment: Then the link to the "duplicate" is enough, I don't need to answer an already answered question again ^^