# NodeJS - Require and Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototypal-inheritance

Does [require](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm) and [module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) in **NodeJS** could be used to obtain all functions in all JavaScript files residing in a directory rather than in a single JavaScript file? 
If so HOW?
 Could anyone please explain it with an ***example*** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js require all files in a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364928/node-js-require-all-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If require is given the directory path, it'll look for an index.js file in that directory. So putting your module specific js files in a directory, creating an index.js file & finally require that directory in your working js file should do. Hope example below helps....

Example:

file: modules/moduleA.js

```
function A (msg) {
    this.message = msg;
}
module.exports = A;
```

file: modules/moduleB.js

```
function B (num) {
    this.number = num;
}
module.exports = B;
```

file: modules/index.js

```
module.exports.A = require("./moduleA.js");
module.exports.B = require("./moduleB.js");
```

file: test.js

```
var modules = require("./modules");
var myMsg = new modules.A("hello");
var myNum = new modules.B("000");
console.log(myMsg.message);
console.log(myNum.number);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using require 
you required the module in that file and you can use the all function of that prototype (single file ) not a complete directory. 
e.g

```
    function admin(admin_id)
{
    //console.log(parent_id);
    this.admin_id = admin_id;
}
//default constructor
function admin()
{
    admin_id = null;
    self =this;
}
//destructor
~function admin(){
    this.admin_id = null;
    console.log('admin obj destroyed!');
    }
//exporting this class to access anywhere through data encapstulation
module.exports = admin;
//class methods

admin.prototype =  {

        help:function(params){

console.log('hi');
}

    },
```

you can require this module and can  use the function help
and by this method u can require all file (modules) in single file

Answer (score 0):

Wiki: "Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform runtime environment for developing server-side Web applications.

Although Node.js is not a JavaScript framework, many of its basic modules are written in JavaScript, and developers can write new modules in JavaScript.

The runtime environment interprets JavaScript using Google's V8 JavaScript engine."

Nodejs example:

You have Afile.js

```
var Afile = function()
{

};

Afile.prototype.functionA = function()
{
    return 'this is Afile';
}

module.exports = Afile;
```

And Bfile.js

```
var Bfile = function()
{

};

Bfile.prototype.functionB = function()
{
    return 'this is Bfile';
}

module.exports = Bfile;
```

The Test.js file require Afile.js and Bfile.js

```
var Afile                         = require(__dirname + '/Afile.js');
var Bfile                         = require(__dirname + '/Bfile.js');

var Test = function()
{

};

Test.prototype.start = function()
{
    var Afile = new Afile();
    var Bfile = new Bfile();

    Afile.functionA();
    Bfile.functionB();
}

var test = Test;
test.start();
```