# Nodejs List of Functions from different files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create an app and the folder structure is as so:

```
./
   index.js
   options/
      basic.js
      help.js
```

js files in the options folder will have objects like so:

```
ping = {
    info: 'text',
    fn: function() {}
}
```

I want index.js to be able to do something like

```
var options = require('./options');
options['ping'].fn();
```

How do I export/require to make it work like this?  My attempts have been futile.

I want to be able to do this without a JS compiler like ES

Comment: `module.exports = ping`. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it).

Comment: then I get cannot find module options

Comment: You need to `require('./options/file_with_your_code.js')` (either `basic` or `help`, you've not mentioned which file your code is in).

Comment: yeah, part of the question was to just require the folder

Comment: It's not clear that you're asking specifically about requiring an entire directory of JavaScript files and somehow merging their implementations into one large object.

Comment: i think its clear, i gave a contrete example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js require all files in a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364928/node-js-require-all-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: nope, that does not accomplish what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `index.js` file inside your `options` folder which exports all of the sibling modules.

```
module.exports = {
    ping: require('./help.js'), // Assuming your "ping" object is here.
    other: require('./basic.js')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JS files (say `filename.js`) in your options folder use `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = {
    info: 'text',
    fn: function() {}
};
```

Then, to consume your module:

```
var options = require('./options/filename.js');
options.fn();
```

This is the [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) approach that NodeJS supports natively for modules.

You won't be able to `require` a folder without resorting to some other tooling, since `require` works at the file level.

From NodeJS's [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules):

> Node.js has a simple module loading system. In Node.js, files and
>   modules are in one-to-one correspondence (each file is treated as a
>   separate module).

Here is a good article to learn more: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: then I get cannot find module './options' in index.js

Comment: try to require: `./options.js`

Comment: options is a folder

Comment: gotcha. I updated my answer. You need to give a direct path to the JS file

Comment: I'm not sure that you can actually require at the folder level...you may need to restructure your code a bit to read from a file...

Comment: Perhaps something like this approach could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364928/node-js-require-all-files-in-a-folder

Comment: this does not accomplish what I want