# Requiring all page objects within a directory recursively for Protractor Specs

Tags: angularjs, selenium, coffeescript, protractor

Suppose I've ordered my page objects files in the following folders:

```
pages
    modals
        modal-1.coffee
        modal-2.coffee
    panels
        panel-1.coffee
        panel-2.coffee
        subpanels
            subpanel-1.coffee
            subpanel-2.coffee
    mainPage.coffee
```

As of right now, I'm requiring each page object individually at the top of my spec files like thus:

```
{Modal1} = require <path to modal-1>
...
{MainPage} = require <path to mainPage>
```

However, I'd like to be able to just make one call, along the lines of:

```
Pages = require <path to pages dir>
```

I found [this SA question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364928/node-js-require-all-files-in-a-folder) and [this blog post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/08/page-objects-angular-protractor-specs/). But I'm getting an error where while the page objects are being read (confirmed with console.log statements in my index.coffee file), their member functions are inaccessible:

```
Pages.MainPage is not a function
Cannot read property 'getSomething' of undefined
```

So my question is - how do I access the member functions of the page objects when I've exported them as a single module Pages?

Any insights would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with coffeescript, but in JS you can try to re-export with 
`index.js`

```
pages
    modals
        modal-1.coffee
        modal-2.coffee
    panels
        panel-1.coffee
        panel-2.coffee
        subpanels
            subpanel-1.coffee
            subpanel-2.coffee
    mainPage.coffee
    index.coffee (?)
```

in your index file:

```
module.exports.modal-1 = require('modals/modal-1.coffee')
module.exports.modal-2 = require('modals/modal-2.coffee')
module.exports.panel-1 = require('panels/panel-1.coffee')
module.exports.mainPage = require('./mainPage.coffee')
// and so on
```

So in specs it would be -

```
let {modal-1, modal-2, mainPage} = require('pages')
```

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules

> If there is no package.json file present in the directory, then
>   Node.js will attempt to load an index.js