# How to reference a directory in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to access a specific directory in javascript. I tried to have access to it using **require** keyword as shown below

```
const path = require('../../var/opt/personal/guest/op/op_12201/data/persGuesOapDataFolder00/');
```

but when i run the code i get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../var/opt/personal/guest/op/op_12201/data/persGuesOapDataFolder00/'
```

please let me know how import or to use a directory in javascript

Comment: What do you expect to happen by importing a directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can't possibly just import a directory unless there is `index.js` file within it. And in that `index.js` file, it should at least contain:

**index.js:**

```
import Foo from './Foo.js'
import Bar from './Bar.js'

export {
    Foo, 
    Bar
}
```

And then you can finally import it:

`import {Foo, Bar} from '../../components';`

Answer (score 0):

When you point to a directory without specifying the file, the index.js file is imported. I do not think it's possible to import an entire directory. If you want to import all the functions of a directory, you can create an index.js and explicitly export them.

See: [node.js require all files in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364928/node-js-require-all-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two different way

consider the following folder structure

```
-- app/
   |- asset/
      |- user.js
   |- main.js
```

here `main.js` you can import the `user.js` in this way `import user from '../asset/user'`

other way is installing `dotenv` using `npm i dotenv --save` and following way

```
require('dotenv').config();
import user from './asset/user
```