# Why is files saying Module not found: Can't resolve be?

Tags: reactjs, url, path

Trying to import my folders but they keep on saying that cannot find folder but the folder I'm import is the correct:

> ./src/LoginPage/Login.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve '../_actions' in >'/Users/mirasmith/Desktop/KPV1-Project-master/src/LoginPage'

I don't know how to show the image so if someone can help fix it. Here the link to the folder hierarchy.

https://gyazo.com/410386debd550039400cf40e9e448196

Comment: show us the import for `../_actions`

Comment: Could you add the source code in Login.js?

Comment: The error message is suggesting that you're trying to import the _actions folder inside the LoginPage folder. You need to take it out one step further.

Comment: `LoginPage` is a directory; without knowing what you're actually doing in your code (e.g., the import itself, and from which file) there's no way to help. It's likely you're just wrong w/ the relative include path, as Stephan said. Questions need to be complete--this is not. Also note that it's pretty easy to get a text-oriented directory tree; images are almost never the best way to communicate information contained in text.

Answer (score 1):

Does _actions have a index.js? When require is given the path of a folder, it'll look for an `index.js` file in that folder. If there is one, it uses it. If not, it doesn't know what file you're trying to import.

If you don't have an index.js in there, you'll need something like:
`"import actions from ../_actions/filename.js"`

If you are trying to do an import of all the files from a folder, this answer talks about how to do that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5365577/5216218

```
import alert from "../_actions/alert.actions.js" 
import user from "../_actions/user.actions.js"
```

Comment: So, I have two index file called alert.actions.js and user.actions.js.

Comment: @BrandonPowell the file itself would be named `index.js`.

Comment: `import alert from "../_actions/alert.actions.js"`

`import user from "../_actions/user.actions.js"`